# Automating export of fs10n query from SAP using VBA

Tags: vba, automation, sap-gui, sap-erp

Currently the manual process exists where users access SAP and select query FS10N to produce a report. This report is then exported from SAP to .XLS format and saved to user's hard drive.

I would like to automate this process with an Excel macro. So far I have implemented VBA code to connect to SAP. So now how do I implement extraction of FS10N report?

Comment: As far as I can see, the data from `FS10N` would be rather hard to extract due to the technology used. Would it be an option to get similar data from the report `RFSSLD00`?

Comment: Hi Vwegert

Thank you for your response.Yes I could use that. How would I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the RFC-enabled function module `INST_EXECUTE_REPORT` to run the report `RFSSLD00` instead of the transaction `FS10N` which is rather hard to remote-control. The basic steps would be:

1. Start the report and save your selection criteria as a variant. Note the name of the variant. Be aware that you can only use inclusion and equality parameters (the black equals sign in a green square) for this way.
2. Run the function module `RS_VARIANT_CONTENTS` using the transaction `SE37` manually. In its table parameters, you will find the values you entered along with the technical parameter names. You will need these when executing the report.
3. From your program, call the function module `INST_EXECUTE_REPORT`, passing the program name and the parameters in the table `PARA`. The list output of the report will be passed back as text in the table `OUTPUT_TAB`.